# Best practice for handling optional parameters in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, get

I'm a beginner in Node JS and Express JS. I'm working on creating an API with which I use a request URL http://localhost:3000/?term=jerry&city=dublin having two parameters. I'm able to get these values using req.query. I want the city to be optional. If there is no value for city is present, the query should  work fine. How can I implement this? I want multiple parameters to be handled in this way. eg. I want the parameter 'term' to be mandatory and all other terms to be optionals in the request http://localhost:3000/?term=jerry&city=dublin&age=25&profession=student. My database is **postgres** and how shall I handle the cases when multiple parameters are optionals and the values are not entered for these parameters. Should I modify my query based on the parameter values? I get 'undefined' for parameters that are not sent with the request URL and my query fails to implement. Can someone help me with the best practices regarding this. I was able to find results for handling queries using req.params.

Adding the method where I handle the request:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var db = require('./db');
  console.log(req.query.term);
  console.log(req.query.country);
  var term = req.query.term;
  var country = req.query.country;
  db.any('SELECT s.official_title, e.gender, e.criteria,  fc.name, fc.email, fc.phone, f.country, c.name, c.downcase_name FROM eligibilities AS e LEFT JOIN studies AS s ON e.nct_id = s.nct_id  LEFT JOIN facility_contacts AS fc ON fc.nct_id = s.nct_id  LEFT JOIN facilities AS f ON f.nct_id = s.nct_id LEFT JOIN conditions AS c ON c.nct_id = s.nct_id GROUP BY s.official_title, e.gender, e.criteria,  fc.name, fc.email, fc.phone, f.country, c.name, c.downcase_name HAVING c.downcase_name LIKE $1 AND f.country LIKE $2 LIMIT 10', ['%' + term + '%', '%' + country + '%']).then(function(data) {
  return res.status(200).send(data);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    return res.status(500).send("There was an error");
  });
});
```

Comment: You should post some of your relevant code.

Comment: You can check for the mandatory parameter and send `400` status if mandatory parameter is not defined.